# evitar código repetitivo y reducir código

Tags: java, android

llevo 3 años realizando una app de un calendario para mi trabajo a base de turnos y equipos que funciona perfectamente pero....
Cada año voy añadiendo cosas nuevas y el código se hace cada vez más complicado y más repetitivo en algunos momentos. Sé que seguro que este código se puede acortar o asociar para que no sea tan repetitivo pero no encuentro la forma. Os adjunto un ejemplo de lo que digo para ver como me podéis echar una mano a resolver este problema.

```
} else if (id == R.id.item_navigation_drawer_grupo) {
        EquipoMeses = EquipoLayout;
        EquipoJuntoMeses = EquipoJuntoLayout;
        mesMeses = MesLayout;



        Intent Elegir_Grupo_Meses = new Intent(this, Elegir_Grupo_Meses.class);
        Elegir_Grupo_Meses.putExtra("mes", mesMeses);
        Elegir_Grupo_Meses.putExtra("mesletra", MesLetra);
        Elegir_Grupo_Meses.putExtra("dia", diaMeses);
        Elegir_Grupo_Meses.putExtra("dianulo", dianuloMeses);
        Elegir_Grupo_Meses.putExtra("diaSemana", diaSemanaMeses);
        Elegir_Grupo_Meses.putExtra("Equipo", EquipoMeses);
        Elegir_Grupo_Meses.putExtra("EquipoJunto", EquipoJuntoMeses);
        Elegir_Grupo_Meses.putExtra("ServicioActivado", ServicioActivadoMeses);
        Elegir_Grupo_Meses.putExtra("PrimeraNotificacion", PrimeraNotificacion);
        Elegir_Grupo_Meses.putExtra("AlarmaConectadaOnOff", AlarmaConectadaOnOffLayout);
        Elegir_Grupo_Meses.putExtra("notificacionlanzada", notificacionlanzada);
        startActivity(Elegir_Grupo_Meses);
        finish();

        } else if (id == R.id.item_navigation_drawer_notificaciones) {
        EquipoMeses = EquipoLayout;
        EquipoJuntoMeses = EquipoJuntoLayout;
        mesMeses = MesLayout;



        Intent QuitarNotificacion = new Intent(this, QuitarNotificacion.class);
        QuitarNotificacion.putExtra("mes", mesMeses);
        QuitarNotificacion.putExtra("mesletra", MesLetra);
        QuitarNotificacion.putExtra("dia", diaMeses);
        QuitarNotificacion.putExtra("dianulo", dianuloMeses);
        QuitarNotificacion.putExtra("diaSemana", diaSemanaMeses);
        QuitarNotificacion.putExtra("Equipo", EquipoMeses);
        QuitarNotificacion.putExtra("EquipoJunto", EquipoJuntoMeses);
        QuitarNotificacion.putExtra("ServicioActivado", ServicioActivadoMeses);
        QuitarNotificacion.putExtra("PrimeraNotificacion", PrimeraNotificacion);
        QuitarNotificacion.putExtra("AlarmaConectadaOnOff", AlarmaConectadaOnOffLayout);
        QuitarNotificacion.putExtra("notificacionlanzada", notificacionlanzada);
        startActivity(QuitarNotificacion);
        finish();

        } else if (id == R.id.item_navigation_drawer_bases) {
        EquipoMeses = EquipoLayout;
        EquipoJuntoMeses = EquipoJuntoLayout;
        mesMeses = MesLayout;


        Intent BackupRestore = new Intent(this, BackupRestore.class);
        BackupRestore.putExtra("mes", mesMeses);
        BackupRestore.putExtra("mesletra", MesLetra);
        BackupRestore.putExtra("dia", diaMeses);
        BackupRestore.putExtra("dianulo", dianuloMeses);
        BackupRestore.putExtra("diaSemana", diaSemanaMeses);
        BackupRestore.putExtra("Equipo", EquipoMeses);
        BackupRestore.putExtra("EquipoJunto", EquipoJuntoMeses);
        BackupRestore.putExtra("ServicioActivado", ServicioActivadoMeses);
        BackupRestore.putExtra("PrimeraNotificacion", PrimeraNotificacion);
        BackupRestore.putExtra("AlarmaConectadaOnOff", AlarmaConectadaOnOffLayout);
        BackupRestore.putExtra("notificacionlanzada", notificacionlanzada);
        startActivity(BackupRestore);
        finish();
```

}

como veis este código se repite en este ejemplo hasta en 3 veces siendo lo mismo, pero esta situación se repite en 6 veces en esta activity y se repite en casi todas las activitys. ¿Habría alguna forma de crear un procedimiento para no tener que repetir siempre el mismo código y poderlo llamar de alguna manera simple?

```
if (MesCompManana == 6 ||MesCompNoche == 6) {
            switch (Grupo) {
                case 1:
                    if (MesCompManana == 6){
                        int CasillaCompManana1 = CasillaInicio + DiaCompManana - 1;
                        String imageCompManana1 = "dia_comp_manana";
                        int drawableIdManana1 = getResources().getIdentifier(imageCompManana1, "drawable", getPackageName());
                        Casilla[CasillaCompManana1].setBackgroundDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(drawableIdManana1));
                        break;

                    } else if (MesCompNoche == 6){
                        int CasillaCompNoche1 = CasillaInicio + DiaCompNoche - 1;
                        String imageCompNoche1 = "dia_comp_noche";
                        int drawableIdNoche1 = getResources().getIdentifier(imageCompNoche1, "drawable", getPackageName());
                        Casilla[CasillaCompNoche1].setBackgroundDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(drawableIdNoche1));
                        break;
                    }
                case 2:
                    if (MesCompManana == 6){
                        int CasillaCompManana1 = CasillaInicio + DiaCompManana - 1;
                        String imageCompManana1 = "dia_comp_manana";
                        int drawableIdManana1 = getResources().getIdentifier(imageCompManana1, "drawable", getPackageName());
                        Casilla[CasillaCompManana1].setBackgroundDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(drawableIdManana1));
                        break;

                    } else if (MesCompNoche == 6){
                        int CasillaCompNoche1 = CasillaInicio + DiaCompNoche - 1;
                        String imageCompNoche1 = "dia_comp_noche";
                        int drawableIdNoche1 = getResources().getIdentifier(imageCompNoche1, "drawable", getPackageName());
                        Casilla[CasillaCompNoche1].setBackgroundDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(drawableIdNoche1));
                        break;
                    }
                case 3:
                    if (MesCompManana == 6){
                        int CasillaCompManana1 = CasillaInicio + DiaCompManana - 1;
                        String imageCompManana1 = "dia_comp_manana";
                        int drawableIdManana1 = getResources().getIdentifier(imageCompManana1, "drawable", getPackageName());
                        Casilla[CasillaCompManana1].setBackgroundDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(drawableIdManana1));
                        break;

                    } else if (MesCompNoche == 6){
                        int CasillaCompNoche1 = CasillaInicio + DiaCompNoche - 1;
                        String imageCompNoche1 = "dia_comp_noche";
                        int drawableIdNoche1 = getResources().getIdentifier(imageCompNoche1, "drawable", getPackageName());
                        Casilla[CasillaCompNoche1].setBackgroundDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(drawableIdNoche1));
                        break;
                    }
                case 4:
                    if (MesCompManana == 6){
                        int CasillaCompManana1 = CasillaInicio + DiaCompManana - 1;
                        String imageCompManana1 = "dia_comp_manana";
                        int drawableIdManana1 = getResources().getIdentifier(imageCompManana1, "drawable", getPackageName());
                        Casilla[CasillaCompManana1].setBackgroundDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(drawableIdManana1));
                        break;

                    } else if (MesCompNoche == 6){
                        int CasillaCompNoche1 = CasillaInicio + DiaCompNoche - 1;
                        String imageCompNoche1 = "dia_comp_noche";
                        int drawableIdNoche1 = getResources().getIdentifier(imageCompNoche1, "drawable", getPackageName());
                        Casilla[CasillaCompNoche1].setBackgroundDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(drawableIdNoche1));
                        break;
                    }
                case 5:
                    if (MesCompManana == 6){
                        int CasillaCompManana1 = CasillaInicio + DiaCompManana - 1;
                        String imageCompManana1 = "dia_comp_manana";
                        int drawableIdManana1 = getResources().getIdentifier(imageCompManana1, "drawable", getPackageName());
                        Casilla[CasillaCompManana1].setBackgroundDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(drawableIdManana1));
                        break;

                    } else if (MesCompNoche == 6){
                        int CasillaCompNoche1 = CasillaInicio + DiaCompNoche - 1;
                        String imageCompNoche1 = "dia_comp_noche";
                        int drawableIdNoche1 = getResources().getIdentifier(imageCompNoche1, "drawable", getPackageName());
                        Casilla[CasillaCompNoche1].setBackgroundDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(drawableIdNoche1));
                        break;
                    }
                case 6:
                    if (MesCompManana == 6){
                        int CasillaCompManana1 = CasillaInicio + DiaCompManana - 1;
                        String imageCompManana1 = "dia_comp_manana";
                        int drawableIdManana1 = getResources().getIdentifier(imageCompManana1, "drawable", getPackageName());
                        Casilla[CasillaCompManana1].setBackgroundDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(drawableIdManana1));
                        break;

                    } else if (MesCompNoche == 6){
                        int CasillaCompNoche1 = CasillaInicio + DiaCompNoche - 1;
                        String imageCompNoche1 = "dia_comp_noche";
                        int drawableIdNoche1 = getResources().getIdentifier(imageCompNoche1, "drawable", getPackageName());
                        Casilla[CasillaCompNoche1].setBackgroundDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(drawableIdNoche1));
                        break;
                    }
                case 7:
                    if (MesCompManana == 6){
                        int CasillaCompManana1 = CasillaInicio + DiaCompManana - 1;
                        String imageCompManana1 = "dia_comp_manana";
                        int drawableIdManana1 = getResources().getIdentifier(imageCompManana1, "drawable", getPackageName());
                        Casilla[CasillaCompManana1].setBackgroundDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(drawableIdManana1));
                        break;

                    } else if (MesCompNoche == 6){
                        int CasillaCompNoche1 = CasillaInicio + DiaCompNoche - 1;
                        String imageCompNoche1 = "dia_comp_noche";
                        int drawableIdNoche1 = getResources().getIdentifier(imageCompNoche1, "drawable", getPackageName());
                        Casilla[CasillaCompNoche1].setBackgroundDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(drawableIdNoche1));
                        break;
                    }
                case 8:
                    if (MesCompManana == 6){
                        int CasillaCompManana1 = CasillaInicio + DiaCompManana - 1;
                        String imageCompManana1 = "dia_comp_manana";
                        int drawableIdManana1 = getResources().getIdentifier(imageCompManana1, "drawable", getPackageName());
                        Casilla[CasillaCompManana1].setBackgroundDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(drawableIdManana1));
                        break;

                    } else if (MesCompNoche == 6){
                        int CasillaCompNoche1 = CasillaInicio + DiaCompNoche - 1;
                        String imageCompNoche1 = "dia_comp_noche";
                        int drawableIdNoche1 = getResources().getIdentifier(imageCompNoche1, "drawable", getPackageName());
                        Casilla[CasillaCompNoche1].setBackgroundDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(drawableIdNoche1));
                        break;
                    }

            }
        }
```

Aquí os muestro otro ejemplo de lo que os comento, este ejemplo se repite en 4 ocasiones cambiando solo una serie de variables pero el código es prácticamente exacto. Repetición de la misma función pero no tengo manera de reducir el código.

Ya os he comentado que la app funciona perfectamente, pero no me gusta como está quedando el código de cargado y cada vez me cuesta más entenderlo hasta a mí.

Me gustaría aprender más en este sentido de organización y distribución de código pero no se donde acudir ya que en mi ciudad no existen academias de programación.

Espero que me podáis ayudar y darme algunas ideas.

Aquí os añado otro trozo de código el cual no soy tampoco capaz de reducir por si me podéis dar alguna idea.

```
 @Override
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    if (MesLetra == MesAnoPasado || MesLetra == MesAnoViene){
        ToastPersonalizado miToast = new ToastPersonalizado(this, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        miToast.show("En este mes no puedes introducir notas");
    } else {

        switch (v.getId()){

            case R.id.TxtVCasilla1:
                TextView txtvcasilla1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TxtVCasilla1);
                TextoCasilla = txtvcasilla1.getText();
                if (txtvcasilla1.getText() == null) {
                    AquiNoPuedes();
                    break;
                } else {
                    PasarDatosNotas();
                    return true;
                }

            case R.id.TxtVCasilla2:
                TextView txtvcasilla2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TxtVCasilla2);
                TextoCasilla = txtvcasilla2.getText();
                if (txtvcasilla2.getText() == null) {
                    AquiNoPuedes();
                    break;
                } else {
                    PasarDatosNotas();
                    return true;
                }

            case R.id.TxtVCasilla3:
                TextView txtvcasilla3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TxtVCasilla3);
                TextoCasilla = txtvcasilla3.getText();
                if (txtvcasilla3.getText() == null) {
                    AquiNoPuedes();
                    break;
                } else {
                    PasarDatosNotas();
                    return true;
                }
```

...

```
            case R.id.TxtVCasilla41:
                TextView txtvcasilla41 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TxtVCasilla41);
                TextoCasilla = txtvcasilla41.getText();
                if (txtvcasilla41.getText() == null) {
                    AquiNoPuedes();
                    break;
                } else {
                    PasarDatosNotas();
                    return true;
                }

            case R.id.TxtVCasilla42:
                TextView txtvcasilla42 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TxtVCasilla42);
                TextoCasilla = txtvcasilla42.getText();
                if (txtvcasilla42.getText() == null) {
                    AquiNoPuedes();
                    break;
                } else {
                    PasarDatosNotas();
                    return true;
                }

        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda por adelantado.

Comment: no entiendo para que tienes el case si haces exactamente igual indiferentemente cual sea el grupo, tampoco se porque un elseif si previamente tienes un if general que ya sabes que va a entrar con una de las dos opciones

Comment: Leyendo de forma rápida tu código: en el primer bloque de `if` que muestras, el cual dices que se repite hasta 6 veces con los mismos datos lo podrías simplificar de la siguiente manera: Creando un método al cual le pasarás dos parámetros: 1) un `Map` o un `Array` con los datos que pones en el `Map` tales como `QuitarNotificacion.putExtra("mes", mesMeses);` y 2) El `Intent` con el que vas a trabajar.  De ese modo los `if` no serían necesarios. Nota: Esto es sólo una sugerencia, aunque no sé lo que ocurre antes de llegar a los `if`...

Comment: Lo de los case es porque en un principio cada case tendría que hacer añadir un tipo diferente de casilla en cada case, pero tendría que repetir aun más el código y decidí añadir unas casillas genéricas con lo cual efectivamente me sobran los case.
Con relación a los else if efectivamente en esos casos no son necesarios pero por rutina los he puesto ahí también. los quitaré.
Con respecto al Map o al Array no tengo ni idea de como implementar eso en el código, en ese ejemplo es parte del navigation_drawer

Comment: en Android Studio,  selecciona el código repetido, click derecho -> REFACTOR -> EXTRACT -> METHOD .  done!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Te propongo estas mejoras.

He comentado lo esencial en el código.

### Primer bloque

Dentro de los condicionales puedes determinar qué `Intent` se va a usar y al final llamas un método y le pasas el `Intent`.
    ...

```
} else if (id == R.id.item_navigation_drawer_grupo) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, Elegir_Grupo_Meses.class);

} else if (id == R.id.item_navigation_drawer_notificaciones) {

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, QuitarNotificacion.class);

} else if (id == R.id.item_navigation_drawer_bases) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, BackupRestore.class);
}

//Fuera del if, myIntent tendrá un valor u otro según lo ocurrido
//Llamas el método y le pasas el Intent

ejecutarIntent(myIntent);

    private void ejecutarIntent(Intent myIntent) {
        EquipoMeses = EquipoLayout;
        EquipoJuntoMeses = EquipoJuntoLayout;
        mesMeses = MesLayout;
        myIntent.putExtra("mes", mesMeses);
        myIntent.putExtra("mesletra", MesLetra);
        myIntent.putExtra("dia", diaMeses);
        myIntent.putExtra("dianulo", dianuloMeses);
        myIntent.putExtra("diaSemana", diaSemanaMeses);
        myIntent.putExtra("Equipo", EquipoMeses);
        myIntent.putExtra("EquipoJunto", EquipoJuntoMeses);
        myIntent.putExtra("ServicioActivado", ServicioActivadoMeses);
        myIntent.putExtra("PrimeraNotificacion", PrimeraNotificacion);
        myIntent.putExtra("AlarmaConectadaOnOff", AlarmaConectadaOnOffLayout);
        myIntent.putExtra("notificacionlanzada", notificacionlanzada);
        startActivity(myIntent);
        finish();
    }
```

### El bloque switch

El código es repetitivo, pero se ve que hace un cierto número de operaciones idénticas cuando el valor de `Grupo` es par o impar. Entonces podemos agrupar esas operaciones comparando si dicho valor es par o impar mediante: `if ( Grupo % 2 == 0 ) {...`. Luego almacenamos variables y establecemos los valores al final.

```
if (MesCompManana == 6 ||MesCompNoche == 6) {
    if ( Grupo % 2 == 0 ) {
               if (MesCompManana == 6){
                    int intCasilla = CasillaInicio + DiaCompManana - 1;
                    String strImagen = "dia_comp_manana";

                } else if (MesCompNoche == 6){
                    int intCasilla = CasillaInicio + DiaCompNoche - 1;
                    String strImagen = "dia_comp_noche";
                }
}else{


                if (MesCompManana == 6){
                    int intCasilla = CasillaInicio + DiaCompManana - 1;
                    String strImagen = "dia_comp_manana";

                } else if (MesCompNoche == 6){
                    int intCasilla = CasillaInicio + DiaCompNoche - 1;
                    String strImagen = "dia_comp_noche";
                }    
}           

//Saliendo de las condicionales, los valores serán únicos 
//por lo que no tenía sentido repetir lo mismo dentro

int myDrawable = getResources().getIdentifier(strImagen, "drawable", getPackageName());
Casilla[intCasilla].setackgroundDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(myDrawable));
```

Sospecho que, con más conocimiento del contexto el código se podría mejorar aún.  Pero ya con esto, te quitarás varias decenas de líneas de código.

Comment: No te haces una idea de como he ha ayudado tu respuesta, he quitado más de 100 lineas de código más de 100 y de 200 ya que esto lo tengo implementado en varios activitys. No se como mostrarte el código final después de probarlo.

Comment: @user3737118 me alegro de que te haya ayudado. Había un error en la última línea, ahora lo he corregido, porque tenía esto `getDrawable(drawableIdNoche1)` en lugar de `getDrawable(myDrawable)`.

Comment: igual creo que el grupo %2 no es necesario , creo que validar solo si de dia o de noche tiene

Answer (score 3):

Veo que ya te dieron una buena respuesta, igualmente me gustaria compartirte un par de observaciones que hice yo, igual te ayuda a simplificar un poco mas

Al tener solo 2 valores posible yo decido iniciarlo por default en los valores de día y en caso de no ser los adecuados los cambiaria por los valores correctos, si lo prefieres podrias simplemente declarar primero y despues inicializar con el valor adecuado

```
int diaComp = DiaCompManana;
String imageComp = "dia_comp_manana";
if (MesCompNoche == 6){//la parte de día se omite al estar implicito en la declaración
    diaComp = DiaCompNoche;
    imageComp = "dia_comp_noche";
}
```

una vez que tenemos los valores los usamos y hacemos uso de los valores determinados

```
int casillaComp = CasillaInicio + diaComp-1 ;
int drawableId = getResources().getIdentifier(imageComp, "drawable", getPackageName());
Casilla[casillaComp].setBackgroundDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(drawableId));
```

otra opción seria no tener que declara casillaComp, usando los valores que ya teniamos ya que no nos sirve para otras operaciones

```
Casilla[CasillaInicio + diaComp -1].setBackgroundDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(drawableId));
```

se declara una unica vez en alguna clase y puede usarse en otra clase atraves de un switch

```
public enum intents {
    ELEGIR_GRUPO_MESES(1,"Elegir_Grupo_Meses"),
    QUITAR_NOTIFICACION(2,"QuitarNotificacion"),
    BACKUP_RESTORE(3,"BackupRestore");

    private Integer intent;
    private String name;

    private intents(Integer intent,String name){
        this.intent = intent;
        this.name =name;
    }

    private static final Map<Integer,intents> map;
    static {
        map = new HashMap<Integer,intents>();
        for (intents v : intents.values()) {
            map.put(v.intent, v);
        }
    }

    public static intents findByKey(int i) {
        return map.get(i);
    }
}
```

con esto nos aseguramos de siempre tener inicializada myIntent, ya que el switch seguramente va a retornar un error si no se encuentra declarada en el enum, para mi esta forma le da mucha mas claridad al codigo, el desarrollo se vuelve mas simple al solo tener que agregar una opcion en el enum y posteriormete en el switch cada que quiera crear un nuevo componente

```
Intent myIntent;
switch(filiales.findByKey(filial)){
    case ELEGIR_GRUPO_MESES:
        myIntent = new Intent(this, Elegir_Grupo_Meses.class);
        break;
    case QUITAR_NOTIFICACION:
        myIntent = new Intent(this, QuitarNotificacion.class);
        break;
    case BACKUP_RESTORE:
        myIntent = new Intent(this, BackupRestore.class);
        break;
}

ejecutarIntent(myIntent);
```

si mes letra es diferente de MesAnoActual, aunque preferiria manejar esto en el front

```
 @Override
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    if (!MesLetra.equals(MesAnoActual)){
        ToastPersonalizado miToast = new ToastPersonalizado(this, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        miToast.show("En este mes no puedes introducir notas");
    } else {
        TextView txtvcasilla;
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.TxtVCasilla1:
                txtvcasilla = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TxtVCasilla1);
                break;
            ....
            case R.id.TxtVCasilla41:
                txtvcasilla = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TxtVCasilla41
                break;
        }
        TextoCasilla = txtvcasilla.getText();//esto quizas lo usas en otra operacion por eso no la elimino
        if (txtvcasilla.getText() == null) {
            AquiNoPuedes();
            break;
        } else {
            PasarDatosNotas();
            return true;
        }
```

en mi opinion el sistema tiene mucha dependencia de una numeración consecutiva, lo cual trataria de abandonar, fuera de eso te quedaria leer mucho ya que asi es la unica forma de aprender continuamente.

espero aun sirva de algo.

Comment: Muchas gracias, si me ha servido pero para modificar otra parte de código. No acabo de aprender cosas gracias a todos vosotros. Estoy seguro que mi código se podría mejorar al 100% pero funcionar funciona así que tendré que ir mejorándolo poco a poco. ¿Por cierto como os podría enviar más código y así ver como podríamos optimizarlo? no se si se puede.

Answer (score 0):

Veo que ya dieron la solución que pensaba en java, pero te recomendaría empezar a utilizar Kotlin ya que es un lenguaje muy sencillo, interoperable al 100% con java y te ahorra mucho codigo que puede llegar a ser repetitivo. un pequeño ejemplo es como muchos asignamos un onClick a un boton, por ejemplo:

java

```
boton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.helloButton);
boton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mifuncion();
        }
    });
```

kotlin

```
helloButton.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener { mifuncion() })
```

Te dejo un enlace directo a la documentación oficial de [kotlin aqui](http://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/)

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado la respuesta para la ultima parte, en la que se repite el ciclo del TextView. Aquí os dejo el código por si os sirve de ayuda.

```
@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    if (MesLetra == MesAnoPasado || MesLetra == MesAnoViene){
        ToastPersonalizado miToast = new ToastPersonalizado(this, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        miToast.show("En este mes no puedes introducir notas");
    } else {

        int casilla = v.getId();

        TextView txtvcasilla = (TextView)findViewById(casilla);
        TextoCasilla = txtvcasilla.getText();
        if (txtvcasilla.getText() == null) {
            AquiNoPuedes();
        } else {
            PasarDatosNotas();
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;

}
```

Como veis se acorta el código en un 99%.

Gracias por vuestra ayuda, seguiré preguntando por otros detalles y dudas que tengo.